# Prepare NSPredicate for HMLocationEvent

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, homekit

My requirement is have to create HMEventTrigger for accessory and location events. Ex: I have an accessory called acc1 and it is having power characteristic. For example I want to create the HMEventTrigger if the acc1 is on and when I am arriving to some location. In that case I have created the predicates for acc1 like below

**Predicate for HMCharacteristicWriteAction**

```
HMCharacteristicWriteAction *chWr = [writeActionsArr objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSPredicate *pred1 = [HMEventTrigger predicateForEvaluatingTriggerWithCharacteristic:chWr.characteristic relatedBy:NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType toValue:chWr.targetValue];
```

**Predicate for HMLocationEvent**

```
HMLocationEvent *b = (HMLocationEvent*)[locationsArr objectAtIndex:0];
NSDateComponents *com = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSPredicate *pred2 = [HMEventTrigger predicateForEvaluatingTriggerOccurringOnDateWithComponents:com];
```

**EX: IF ACC1.ON AND LOCATIONEVENT THEN PERFORM HMACTIONSET**

If I combine both the pred1 and pred2 objects it is also including the current date but I don't want to include the date. So I have to create the trigger with the pred1 and pred2 without including the time or date, Only have to include the location. Thank you for reading my post. Any ideas/suggestion are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem statement is not clear.  Maybe create a new `HMEventTrigger` with the location event as the only object in the `events` array?

```
HMHome *home = ... // home
HMLocationEvent *locationEvent = ... // your event variable
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init]; // create your date components
HMEventTrigger *trigger = [[HMEventTrigger alloc] initWithName:@"eventName" events:@[locationEvent] predicate:[HMEventTrigger predicateForEvaluatingTriggerOccurringOnDateWithComponents:dateComponents]];
[home addTrigger:trigger completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
     // ...
 }];
```

Comment: HI Jal Thank you for answering the question. My issue is I have to combine HMCharacteristicWriteAction and HMLocation Event conditions.Ex:if acc1.ch is On AND location.region then I have to perform the HMActionSet.